# showCheckbox="true" not shown on p:selectManyMenu

Tags: primefaces

PLEASE help me resovle this proplem, i SEE on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyMenu.jsf.

About p:selectManyMenu, i used it, but when i put it in my page the component showCheckbox="true" inside p:selectManyMenu is not show.
I am using primefaces 3.4.1

SO, HOW CAN I USE IT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showCheckbox` attribute is not supported for `p:selectManyMenu` in PrimeFaces 3.4 ([docs](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf)). You will need to [download](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html) PrimeFaces 3.5 ([docs](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf)).